# build.gradle file having problems building, unresolved 'No such property error'

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

This is the content of my build.gradle file of api module. It is shooting out the below mentioned error.

```
version "1.1.0"

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'


// Android support
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.3-beta'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url: "http://orchard.internal.mohc.net:8081/artifactory/libs-${version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT") ? "snapshot" : "release"}-local") {
            authentication(userName: artifactoryUsername, password: artifactoryPassword)
        }
    }
}
```

error: Error:(18, 0) No such property: artifactoryUsername for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

points to line 18. Does anyone knows whats going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see in your error message, Gradle is trying to find the property artifactoryUsername, which is actually a value for the property. Use double quotes for username and password.

```
uploadArchives {
repositories.mavenDeployer {
    repository(url: "http://orchard.internal.mohc.net:8081/artifactory/libs-${version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT") ? "snapshot" : "release"}-local") {
        authentication(userName: "artifactoryUsername", password: "artifactoryPassword")
        }
    }
}
```

You can see example [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html).

Comment: You are right. I have removed that statement. Despite, use quotes in build.gradle file.

Comment: Technically, it's a Groovy file, but yes quoted strings are necessary